# Pricing a call option in the Black Scholes Market - calculation steps

Tags: stochastic-calculus, finance, stochastic-integrals

I am working on computing the price of a standard European call option under a Black-Scholes market.

Using knowledge of the payoff, I can split the calculation into:

$
e^{-rT}(E[S_t] \mathbb{1}_{S_T > K} - KE[\mathbb{1}_{S_T > K}]
$

for which the expected value of the indicator function is simply:

$P[S_T >K]$

Using the formula for $S_T$ as a Brownian motion I can derive a $Z = \frac{lnS_T - (lnS_0 +r - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})T)}{\sigma \sqrt{T}} $ ~ $ N(0, 1)$

and thus the calculation for the probability (second term) leads to $N(d_\_)$

However, I am struggling to compute the first term. Doing

$E[S_T \mathbb{1}_{S_T >K}] = E [S_o exp(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})T + \sigma W_T) \mathbb{1}_{S_T > K}]$, in my notes leads to:

$E[S_o exp(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})T + \sigma \sqrt{T}Z) \mathbb{1}_{Z> -d_+ + \sigma \sqrt{T}}]$, which I can not follow where it comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from simply rewriting the expression $S_T > K$.  The following inequalities are all equivalent:
\begin{align*}
S_T &> K \\
S_0 \exp\left( \left(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T + \sigma \sqrt{T}Z\right) &> K \\
\left(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T + \sigma \sqrt{T}Z &> \ln\left(\frac{K}{S_0}\right) \\
Z &> \frac{\ln (K/S_0) - \left(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T}{\sigma \sqrt T} \\
Z &> -\left( \frac{\ln (S_0/K) + \left(r+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T}{\sigma \sqrt T}\right) + \sigma \sqrt T.
\end{align*}
Since $$d+ = \frac{\ln (S_0/K) + \left(r+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T}{\sigma \sqrt T},$$ we have that $1_{S_T > K} = 1_{Z > -d_+ + \sigma \sqrt T}$.

Comment: Going over this again, where does the $+ \sigma \sqrt{T}$ come from in the final line?

Comment: The line before it has a term that is $+\frac{\sigma}{2} \sqrt T$ (if you split off the last term in the fraction), but $-d_+$ has a term with $-\frac{\sigma}{2} \sqrt T$, so we need to add back on $\sigma \sqrt T$ to make the lines the same.